# win_iis_webapppool not setting password to apppool SpecificUser

Tags: iis, ansible

The following snippet of module is creating app pool with specified user name but not setting the password.

```
- name: Create GRSClient application pool
  win_iis_webapppool:
    name: "Test"
    state: started
    attributes:
      managedRuntimeVersion: v4.0
      managedPipelineMode: Integrated
      processModel.identityType: SpecificUser
      processModel.userName: 'TestUser'
      processModel.password: 'TestPassword'
      processModel.loadUserProfile: false
      enable32BitAppOnWin64: true
      failure.rapidFailProtection: true
      processmodel.idleTimeout: 00:20:00
      processmodel.idleTimeoutAction: Terminate
      startMode: AlwaysRunning
```

Comment: Please check your applicationhost.config file and find application pool section. Then find the pool which name is TestUser. Please fully show this part to let us  check which setting has been set and which not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any error message? I tried what you created and it set successfully, how did you check application pool user password? When I tried to see what it set from cmd with command below

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list config /section:applicationpools
```

I could see :

```
<add name="ansiblepool">
      <processModel identityType="SpecificUser" userName="TestUser" password="TestPassword" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons for this problem:

1. Incorrect user name or password
2. The user might not be a local user or domain user

As per my understanding, you'll run into this issue in either of these cases.